# Unable to get SelectList working in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms

I am trying to get my `SelectList` working. I tried adding the options in the model class, but I'm unable to get that working with an error

> Member Testing.TaxIDType cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

which I am not sure about how to fix.

I added the `SelectList` items to my model:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> TaxIDType = new List<SelectListItem>()
{
    new SelectListItem() { Text = "FEIN", Value = "FEIN" },
    new SelectListItem() { Text = "SSN", Value = "SSN" }
};
```

I try to call the in the view using the following statement.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.TaxIDType, class.TaxIDType)
```

I am getting the following two errors:

> 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'TaxIDType' and no accessible extension method 'TaxIDType' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

---

> Member 'Testing.TaxIDType' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a step by step explanation of using **DropDownListFor** helper in your case.

1. Create a model which will contain a collection of *SelectListItem* instances.

   ```
   public class MyModel
   {
       public List<SelectListItem> TaxIDType = new List<SelectListItem>()
       {
           new SelectListItem() { Text = "FEIN", Value = "FEIN" },
           new SelectListItem() { Text = "SSN", Value = "SSN" }
       };
   }
   ```

Note: if you want, you can even make the property `static`, however, you will need to change the way you reference the property on the view (will explain it eventually)

2. Create the model and pass it to the view.

   ```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       var viewModel = new MyModel();
       return View(viewModel);
   }
   ```
3. In the view, state that your view uses MyModel class. You can do it by putting the `@model` helper on the top of your view (`.cshtml` file).

   ```
    @model WebApplication3.Controllers.MyModel
   ```

Here, `WebApplication3.Controllers` is a namespace of your model and `MyModel` is it's name. Don't use the listed namespace and model, but change them to your own.

4. Use the DropDownListFor helper as following

   ```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => ??, Model.TaxIDType)
   ```

In the example, Model is a property which is being populated by the framework to let your acecss a class instance which you passes in `View()` method inside the controller. (`MyModel` instance in this case).
By writing Model.TaxIDType you are referencing the property which contains the list of items to poppulate the dropdown.
Notice, that the property in the model isn't marked as `static`, that's why we have to access it via the instance (Model) reference. However, you can, indeed, make the property `static`. In that case, you will need to change the usage in the view to the following:

```
     @Html.DropDownListFor(x => ??, MyModel.TaxIDType)
```

The last thing to mention: take a look at the question marks. In order to get the selected value back, you will need to map it to the model. One way to do it is to extend the model.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string SelectedTaxIdType { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> TaxIDType = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "FEIN", Value = "FEIN" },
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "SSN", Value = "SSN" }
    };
}
```

and than modify the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedTaxIdType, Model.TaxIDType)
```

Comment: I am sorry that I forgot to add the second error in the code. Can you check that and also, the error still persists after making the changes in the view. Please and thank you.

Comment: What's your model type ? check it in @model statement.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't figure out how. I tried to place this statement in the my view and nothing is coming up. Not displaying anything even with breakpoint.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I made the changes as per your suggestion skipping step 2 as the dropdown list in the same model. However, I am still getting the Compiler error for step 4: "CS0176: Member 'Testing.TaxIDType' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead".

Comment: Oleksandr, I have another question in the loop regarding the same. Can you answer that instead? I will have both the answers upvoted.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61326726/data-field-select-based-on-dropdown-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Harsha, i don't have enough time to answer your second question right now. I'll try to check it later, but don't promise anything. Regarding upvoting: it's up to you to decide whether the answer was usefull or not.

Comment: I tried to verify all the statements giving by you. I am sure what you have given was right. But, just that I isn't working for me.

Comment: Oleksandr, I figured out what was the issue with my code earlier. I was trying to pass it as static and it refused to. I was able to use the same method for a different dropdown. Thank you.